# Scraping text and images from a word document

Tags: java, python, ruby, ms-word

I have been trying to scrape the text and Images from a word document(2003,07,10)

The doc consists of questions and answers, I need to scrape the doc and retrieve them accordingly.

I have tried conversion of a .doc to .html using MS-WORD 2013 i.e File->SaveAs-->html and then scrape it.

I need your help and valuable suggestions on,

Converting the doc to html including the images in it using any programming language[I have experience in Java & Python] and whichever actually works.

Is there a way I could parse the .doc without conversion to .html and scrape from it.

You can find files here: http://bit.ly/1ifjps9
[including .htm,.doc and images]

Comment: Have you tried [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org)?

Comment: Is this being done on a Windows system with Office installed?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using these languages and not just using `vba`. `VBA` is far less graceful but will do what you want perfectly.

Comment: Convert to docx, and scrape that, using docx4j or POI.